# ElasticSearch v1.4 Recover Lost data

Tags: elasticsearch

After restarting cluster I lose my data,How Can I recover it 
ElasticSearch Version 1.4

```
    {
    "cluster_name": "mycluster",
    "status": "yellow",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 1,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
    "active_primary_shards": 113,
    "active_shards": 113,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 110
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"status": "yellow"` means that not all the replicas could be assigned (actually `"unassigned_shards": 110`), but all your primary shards and thus all your data is there: `"active_primary_shards": 113,`

Why are the replicas not allocated? Because you only have a single node in your cluster: `"number_of_nodes": 1,`. So either only one node is up or if there are multiple ones then they couldn't form a cluster (more details should be in the logs then).

Generally, your Elasticsearch version is ancient and a lot has been improved around resiliency. If you value your data, start planning an upgrade.